# postprocess displayed frame/screen on windows/linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, image, screenshot

**Some Background**
I've got an autostereoscopic display that needs the bitmap/frame that is to be rendered on the screen to be interleaved in a specific manner to be displayed in 3d.

For programs that I write my self this is no problem as I have attach a shader to the opengl buffer I am drawing into.

I was wondering whether I can do something similar as a postprocessing step over existing programs, where I do not have access to the rendering pipeline.

**Here's the question**

is there a way to intercept the next frame/screen that will be displayed on the monitor such that I can filter it before the frame can be rendered on the monitor?
My first idea was to create a screenshot and display it as an overlay. But this would be slower. And also I need all keyboard an mouse commands to be passed on to the actual programs running.

I'd be grateful for any ideas. 
(for Linux/ Windows / any language - this is just to be a proof of concept - I don't require a cross plattform solution)